# How to format a web page into frames

Tags: html

I want to divide a jsp page into 3 frames.kindly tell me how to do it

Comment: This really depends on the JSP page in question. There is no single process to do this. Can you provide more information?

Comment: do you mean html <frame>s or something else?

Comment: just don't :) frames are obsolete

Comment: actully i want to do the alignment of my page

Comment: Try to search some tutorials before asking something on something you have no idea what it is.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Java/JSP and everything to do with HTML.  Removed 'java' tag.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use DIV to format your page.

For ex. [jsfiddle : Partitioning the web page using DIV](http://jsfiddle.net/saranghdave/6ECBm/)

For other reference : [w3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/)

I think you will require to learn HTML & CSS. Later try to implement it on JsFiddle (need registration) and then implement in your project.

Thank You.

Comment: If you don't know what <div> is, you need to read some html book/tutorial/etc.